# STL container for a list with random access?

Tags: c++, stl

Is there an STL container similar to a list in that elements of lists are not stored contiguously? The size of this container can be up to 1000x1000 elements with each element being a vector containing 36 doubles. This would be a large chunk to store together (like ~200 megabytes).  Is there a variant that instead stores pointers to its contents as a separate vector so it would allow for random access. Is there an STL container class for this that already exists or should I just store the pointers manually?

The container I need is actually a constant size so I think implementing it myself wouldnt be too difficult, but I was wondering if an STL container already exists for this. I'd like to avoid a vector because the list is large and the contents will be of medium size.  If the vectors in the container don't need to reside next to each other then wouldn't it be better to separate them in a list to prevent running out of memory from fragmentation?

Comment: so... what you want is `std::array<std::unique_ptr<T>, length>`?

Comment: What aspect of the performance of `std::vector<T>` or `std::array<T, n>` are you concerned about?

Comment: if the list is constant sized, then you needn't use a list. Try `std::vector`, `std::deque`, or if your system supports C++11 `std::array`.

Comment: The list will hold vectors, but the list itself doesnt need to be contiguous, so I'm trying to avoid a vector for the overall container.

Comment: OK, you don't need the container to be contiguous.  That isn't a reason to avoid `vector` or `array`!

Comment: Ecatmur can you elaborate? Each of the elements in the container will be something like a 36 element double vector. But the collection of vectors does not need to be contiguous. The container will be very large, so if the vectors in the container don't need to  reside next to each other then wouldn't it be better to separate them in a list to prevent running out of memory?

Comment: Similar to a `list` in what respect? Fast insertion/deletion at an iterator? Elements never relocate? If all you need is a sequence, then the standard sequences (aside from `array`) are `vector`, `deque` and `list`. As far as contiguity is concerned, `vector` is contiguous, `deque` need not be contiguous but it has random access and for ops like insert/remove in the middle it need not be any faster than if it was, `list` is non-contiguous and guarantees the benefits (and drawbacks) of non-contiguity.

Comment: @user1346994: If running out of memory is a concern, use `std::deque` instead of `std::vector`, but I doubt it is a concern.

Comment: 36 doubles occupy 288 bytes minimum, so if by "large" you mean well over a million of those, then that could be difficult to allocate once memory is fragmented and it's also somewhat expensive to resize as a `vector`. In which case `deque` would be preferred to `vector`. Until you can measure a performance problem, `deque` can be preferred to `vector` in general if you like -- it's arguably premature optimization to avoid `deque` when you don't need contiguity. A `deque<array<double, 36>>` is probably reasonable.

Comment: @MooingDuck: it's not clear to me that the outer container *must* hold a vector: for all that the questioner says it will, people are valiantly arguing in favour of `array` for the fixed-size rows, so I wanted to cover that case. But if it does hold a `vector` then agreed. It won't get really big until you're starting to run out of total memory anyway, so it's not going to make a difference of more than (say) a factor of 2-ish in max size that works.

Comment: @SteveJessop similar to a list in that elements of lists are not stored contiguously. The size of this object can be up to 1000x1000 with each element containing 36 doubles. This would be a large chunk to store together (like ~200 megabytes). I'm thinking a deque might be the way to go...

Comment: Personally I'd try a `deque<array>` first. Like MooingDuck says, though, there's no particular reason why a `vector<vector>` shouldn't work. The largest contiguous allocation needed is only `sizeof(vector)*1000*1000`, so a few 10s of MB. However, it will chug a bit when it has to re-allocate in C++03 (not so much C++11), so `vector` is a less good bet if you don't know the size of the matrix up front and hence can't `reserve` it.

Comment: @SteveJessop It's my understanding that you can run out of heap space easier by allocating a 200mb contiguous chunk of memory vs doing two 100mb chunks of memory or breaking it up even more. That's why I wasn't requiring it to be contiguous. Also, I was thinking that with the analysis I'm doing, the l1 cache might fill and eject all the info pertaining to the an element in the container before moving on to the next one and thus contiguity wouldn't provide any benefits with regard to cache misses. I think I'll try a vector<array> first and then move to a deque if I'm having memory issues.

Comment: @user: Don't solve problems you are only *guessing* exist: it's usually a Bad Idea. If you really are concerned that memory fragmentation will be an issue, then *actually test that hypothesis*. Actually implement both the easy array of array solution along with whatever alternate solution you want to try, and see if your alternate solution really does make things better.

Comment: @Hurkyl I think you might be right in that I'm probably over analyzing the situation and/or underestimating the power of modern computing. I think I'll implement the answer first and then go back to the other responses here if I encounter any problems. Thanks again.

Comment: @user1346994: it's not exactly that you run out of heap space, it's that the heap can be in a state where it's capable of satisfying two requests for 100MB, but not capable of satisfying a single request for 200MB. So the result you care about is the same as running out of space, that your attempt to allocate 200MB in one go fails. There's still plenty of free space, but the giant `vector` can't use it.

Comment: @SteveJessop Yes, but my line of thinking is I'd like to avoid the failure of allocating a large chunk of memory regardless of the situation (i.e. actually out of memory or there is just some memory fragmentation problems), which is why I initially thought I should "break it up" by not requiring contiguity. Probably should have been a little more precise with my wording there with regards to "running out of heap space." I think overall I'm just being a little premature with my concerns. I'll explore other options if memory allocation becomes an issue. Thanks for all the comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both `deque<array<double, 36>>` and `vector<vector<double>>` would avoid the need for any really huge contiguous allocations.

The `vector<vector<double>>` is worse in those terms. For the numbers you specify it needs a contiguous allocation of `1000*1000*sizeof(vector<double>)`, which is low 10s of MB (most likely a `vector` is the size of 3 pointers). That's rarely a problem on a "proper computer" (desktop or server). The places where it would be a concern for fragmentation reasons (small virtual address space or no virtual addressing at all), you might also have a more fundamental problem that you don't have 300MB-ish of RAM anyway. But you could play extra-safe by avoiding it, since clearly there can exist environments where you could allocate 300MB total but not 12MB contiguously.

There is no `std::array` in C++03, but there's `boost::array` or you could easily write a class to represent 36 doubles.

`vector<array<double, 36>>` suffers worst from fragmentation, it requires a contiguous 250-MB allocation. Personally I don't find it easy to simulate in testing "the worst possible memory fragmentation we will ever face", but I'm not the best tester. That size of block is about where I start feeling a bit uneasy in a 32 bit process, but it will work fine in good conditions.

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend you to use the `std::array` class. It is constant sized, it supports random access to all elements, and has implementations of `iterator, const_iterator, reverse_iterator, const_reverse_iterator`. More about it: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/array/

Comment: From what I've read the entire array is contiguous. For my application I only want the rows (or columns) to be contiguous.

Comment: @user1346994: just because it doesn't _need_ to be contiguous doesn't mean it can't be contiguous.  Contiguous is _very fast_.  There's reasons we're recommending it.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't clear what characteristic of `std::list<T>` you are after exactly. If you want a container whose elements stay put when adding or removing elements, you might want to have a look at `std::deque<T>`: when adding/removing elements at the front or the back all other element stay at the same location. That is, pointers and references to elements stay valid, unless elements are add or removed in the middle. Iterators get invalid on any insertion or removal. `std::deque<T>` provides random access.

There is no container directly given random access and support addition/removal at any poistion with the elements staying put. However, as others have pointed out, using a container of pointers provides such an interface. It may be necessary to wrap it to hide the use of pointers.